# how to boot from external hard disk with ubuntu installed?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, fedora, kali-linux

i've made a bootable ubuntu 17.10 USB in order to install it on my external HDD, the installation had been completed successfully and i got the ubuntu system in my external HDD, the issue is that i can't by anyway find my external HDD on the list of bootable devices when clicking F12 on my computer.

my computer is configured with the UEFI mode.

all what i want is to run any LINUX OS from an external HDD on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

By boot list, I am assuming the grub menu.  The grub menu only knows about what is already installed on existing hard drives when the grub menu was set up.  If you attach an external drive afterwards, grub will know nothing about it.

The cleanest way to boot off of some other media is to use the boot menu in the firmware.  Usually pressing the F12, F10 or some key like that while the machine is powering up will present you with a list of hard drives to boot from.  You can select your external hard drive from there.

Comment: it doesn't work, this is the problem, i can't see my external hard drive but in the other hand i'm able to boot from my usb ! is it due to the hardware type or sth ?

Comment: Please provide more details.  Where can't you see your external hard drive?  How do you boot from your usb?  Edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Boot menu keys: F6 for Intel Servers, blue button or {Enter} for Lenovo, F12 for Gigabyte, F11 for Supermicro; others shown here https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=58779 .  Please advise the motherboard model no. (or PC model no. from the serial no. plate). Ordinarily, I'd suggest posting your question at https://askubuntu.com, the Stack Exchange site for Ubuntu, but you use a discontinued Ubuntu version; supported versions as per Ubuntu themselves https://www.ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle are 16.04LTS, 18.04LTS (both w/ > 2 yrs support) & interim release 18.10 (6 mo. support).